Want to render an ajax form in a VBO enabled view in drupal 10
I have a VBO Enabled view in Drupal 10. In that view, i have a custom made Field that renders a form field. So it's like a form in a form.
I need to get that form element to submit with ajax, and not being a part of the VBO form. Right now it renders as a part of VBO and getting an error in watchdog.

The specified #ajax callback is empty or not callable

And this in the browser console

Oops, something went wrong. Check your browser's developer console for more details.

The form field could be available for several rows, so it have to be unique for this row.
What am I missing here ?
This is my custom form
PickupStoreForm.php
<?php

namespace Drupal\freecopy\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class PickupStoreForm extends FormBase
{

  public $sub_id = 0;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId()
  {
    return 'freecopy_pickup_store_form_' . $this->sub_id;
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $pickup_store = null)
  {

    $wrapper = 'ajax-wrapper-' . $this->sub_id;

    $vocabulary = 'pickup_stores';
    $terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vocabulary);

    // Prepare options array for the dropdown.
    $options = [];
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
      $options[$term->tid] = $term->name;
    }

    // Add a dropdown field to the form.
    $form['pickup_store_' . $this->sub_id] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => $options,
      '#default_value' => $pickup_store,
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::ajaxCallback',
        'wrapper' => $wrapper,
        'event' => 'change',
      ]
    ];

    $form['result'] = [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<div id="'.$wrapper.'"></div>',
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  public function ajaxCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    // Update data on the row, when fired.
    return [];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
  }

}

And this is my custom Views field
PickupStore.php
<?php

namespace Drupal\freecopy\Plugin\views\field;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Drupal\freecopy\Form\PickupStoreForm;
use Drupal\views\Annotation\ViewsField;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\FieldPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\ResultRow;
use Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * @ViewsField("pickup_store_dropdown")
 */
class PickupStore extends FieldPluginBase
{
  public function __construct(array $configuration,
                              $plugin_id,
                              array $plugin_definition,
                              protected FormBuilderInterface $form_builder
  ) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('form_builder')
    );
  }

  public function query() {}

  public function render(ResultRow $values)
  {

    /** @var WebformSubmission $entity */
    $entity = $this->getEntity($values);
    $submissionData = $entity->getData();

    if ('awaiting' !== $submissionData['status']) {
      return;
    }

    $form = $this->form_builder->getForm(PickupStoreForm::class, $submissionData['pickup_store']);
    $renderedForm = $this->renderer->render($form);

    return [
      '#markup' =>  $renderedForm,
    ];
  }

}

